# xargs not generating correct command

Tags: zsh, xargs

I want to delete a number of apps on an Android device that all begin with the same package. I get these with the following command:

```
$ adb shell ls /data/data | grep -i com.company
com.company.android.app.adwidget
com.company.android.app.attendancereports
com.company.android.app.atteventmanagement
com.company.android.app.buttonwidget
com.company.android.app.clockwidget
```

Now I want to execute `adb uninstall` for each of these package names, I thought of using `xargs`:

```
$ adb shell ls /data/data | grep -i com.company | xargs -n1 echo adb uninstall
adb uninstall com.company.android.app.adwidget
adb uninstall com.company.android.app.attendancereports
adb uninstall com.company.android.app.atteventmanagement
adb uninstall com.company.android.app.buttonwidget
adb uninstall com.company.android.app.clockwidget
```

It looks like it is going to work, so I remove `echo`:

```
$ adb shell ls /data/data | grep -i com.company | xargs -n1 adb uninstall
Failure
Failure
Failure
Failure
Failure
```

However running each command independently yields `Success`:

```
$ adb uninstall com.company.android.app.adwidget
Success
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Not a solution to your problem, but you don't need the `grep`, just use a glob: `adb ls /data/data/*com.company* | xargs -n1 adb uninstall` should do the same thing. Does it work if you do `for i in adb ls /data/data/*com.company*; do  adb uninstall "$i"; done` ?

Comment: Ah, sorry, that should have been `adb shell ls`, not `adb ls`, does that make a difference?

Comment: @terdon, if you don't quote that glob, it will be expanded by the local shell, not the shell running on Android. The output will also be things like `/data/data/something` instead of `something`.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Right, not quoting it still gives me `no matches found`. Quoting it behaves the same as in my question (`Failure` for all executions)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Redirecting the output of `adb shell ls /data/data | grep -i com.company` to a file and examining it with a hexeditor I found out they're appended with Windows-style carriage return `\r\n`  (0x0D 0x0A). So getting rid of the `\r` with `tr -d '\r'` solved the problem.

Whole command using `for` (from [Stéphane Chazelas' answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/363684/131344)):

```
for x in $(adb shell ls /data/data | grep -i com.company | tr -d '\r'); do adb uninstall $x;  done
```

Or similarly using `xargs`:

```
adb shell ls /data/data | grep -i com.company | tr -d '\r' | xargs -r -n1 adb uninstall
```

---

Another option (as kindly explained by Stéphane Chazelas on the comments below) is disabling `\r` altogether with `stty -opost`, although this most likely requires `busybox` (or an alternative like `toybox`) to be installed on the Android device.

```
$ adb shell echo test | sed -n l               
test\r$
$ adb shell 'busybox stty -opost; echo test' | sed -n l
test$
```

Comment: `adb shell 'stty -opost; ls /data/data'` might also work (if those `CR` are introduced because `adb` interacts with a pseudo-terminal on the Android side).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I didn't have the time to test because all packages were uninstalled now. I have to install some again to test.

Comment: [Transferring binary data over ADB shell (ie fast file transfer using tar)](//stackoverflow.com/q/11689511) suggests that's what's happening. `stty raw` includes `stty -opost` which includes `stty -onlcr`. Looking at a man page for that `adb`, it looks like you can also do `adb shell -t` to disable that pty allocation in the first place!

Comment: For your first suggestion: `/system/bin/sh: stty: not found\r$`. About `-t` it doesn't work either:  `error: target doesn't support PTY args -Tt`. Please note this is a quite old Android device (4.1).

Comment: But using `busybox` does the trick indeed: `adb shell 'busybox stty -opost; echo test' | sed -n l` outputs `test$` while `adb shell echo test | sed -n l` outputs `test\r$`. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

Though the problem ended up being [caused by CR characters in the `adb shell` output](/a/363714) (inserted by the tty line discipline of the the pty created on the target Android system (see [here](/q/151916) for more details)), another possible explanation (and I'll leave it there for future readers as that's a common problem with `xargs`) could have been that in:

```
adb shell ls /data/data | grep -i com.company | xargs -n1 adb uninstall
```

depending on the `xargs` implementation, `adb`'s stdin will be either `/dev/null` or the pipe from `grep`. In any case, it won't be the tty and that may be why `adb` fails if it expects to be able to interact with the user.

With GNU `xargs` and a shell with support for process substitution (like `zsh`), you could change it to:

```
xargs -n1 -ra <(adb shell ls /data/data | grep -i com.company) adb uninstall
```

In that case `xargs` reads the list from the file given as argument to `-a` which lets you leave stdin alone.

Or since you're mentioning `zsh`, you could use:

```
autoload zargs # best in ~/.zshrc
zargs -L1 $(adb shell ls /data/data | grep -i com.company) -- adb uninstall
```

(using `-L` instead of `-n` as `zargs`'s `-n` limits the *total* number of arguments to `adb` (including the `uninstall` one) which means we would need `-n 2`).

Or simply use a loop, which would be even shorter and more legible in this case:

```
for x ($(adb shell ls /data/data | grep -i com.company)) adb uninstall $x
```

Comment: Your `xargs` and `for` commands give the same error as my xargs version: `Failure` for all executions. `zargs` command gives me `zargs: argument list too long` (thanks for `zargs` btw)

Comment: @m0skit0, wrap the `for` loop in `(set -x; foo loop here)` and see where that differs from running `adb` by hand. Possibly the output has some trailing carriage return (aka `$'\C-M'`) characters.

Comment: Cool feature. I see no difference, here's the first command output: `+zsh:48> x=com.company.android.app.attendancereports
+zsh:48> adb uninstall com.company.android.app.attendancereports
Failure`. I see no strange characters.

Comment: @m0skit0, and `adb uninstall com.company.android.app.attendancereports` works? Possibly you need to insert some delay between `adb` commands?

Comment: Yes, it works, returns `Success`. No delay is needed, I've made other scripts using `adb` before, but I will try with `sleep`.

Comment: @m0skit0, no way to turn some verbose/debug output on? Nothing in the logs?

Comment: Unfortunately `adb` doesn't have any verbose options. I redirected the output of `adb shell ls /data/data | grep -i com.company` to a file to see if there are any strange characters but there don't seem to be any. Strange stuff...

Comment: @m0skit0, See edit about the `zargs` issue (not that I'd expect it to solve the issue).

Comment: @m0skit0, do you see a difference if you run `strace -fe execve adb` instead of `adb` (in the loop and when by hand)?

Comment: ´zargs´ edit now just outputs `adb uninstall`.

Comment: No difference on `strace`: `execve("/home/yasin/Android/programming/android-sdk/sdk/platform-tools/adb", ["adb", "uninstall", "com.company.android.app.clo"...], [/* 76 vars */]) = 0`

Comment: I finally found the problem examining the output with a hexeditor. The newline character is a double character (Windows-style) `\r\n` (0x0D 0x0A). How was a Windows-style newline introduced is a mystery to me. Sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: @m0skit0, that's the carriage return I was talking of earlier. I'd expect you'd have seen something like `+zsh:48> echo adb uninstall $'com.company.android.app.attendancereports\C-M'` in the `set -x` output above. What's your version of `zsh`?

Comment: My zsh is version 5.0.2. I see that's pretty outdated...

Comment: @m0skit0. Yes, I can reproduce with that version. With a newer version, you'd get the `$'\C-M'` as shown above. Mystery solved.

Comment: Yeah, that's the problem with packaged software... Always outdated. Thank you very much for your help!